What is the value of the ideal gas constant in J/(mol*°C)?
I've seen in some sites that it is the same as in J/(mol*K), is that true?
$8.314 \frac{J}{mol×K}=8.314 \frac{J}{mol×°C}$

In my opinion, it doesn't make sense to write the gas constant in terms of the Celsius scale, because the gas constant shows up in the ideal gas law, where the temperature must be on an absolute scale. That said, if you write $pV = nR (T-T_0)$, where $T$ is understood to be in Celsius and $T_0$ is absolute-zero on the Celsius scale, then I suppose that the equality in your post here is correct.

Does this answer your question? Why is specific heat measured in J/kg °C?
